# Adding the same key to matched pairs

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2

The situation is as follows. After matching a file with itself for deduping purposes we are left up with the following pairs of matched records:

Key1 - Key2
Key1 - Key3
Key2 - Key1
Key2 - Key3
Key3 - Key1
Key3 - Key2

I would like somehow to add a unique cluster key for this so we are left up with all these records under the same key. So in this case we will have a separate key that identifies Key1, Key2 and Key 3 as being one an the same.

Any help is welcome.

Thank you,

Doru

Comment: You have this tagged for both sql-server and db2.  Which database are you really using?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a complete list of keys that are identical to each other.  Let's say that you have a table with these two keys.  The following query returns the *minimum* key value for any given key:

```
select key1,
       (case when key1 < min(key2) over (partition by key1) then key1
             else min(key2) over (partition by key1) 
        end) as newkey
from keypairs kp
group by key1;
```

This gives a lookup value per key.  To apply this to your table (in either SQL Server or DB2):

```
select t.*, coalesce(keymap.newkey, t.key) as newkey
from YourTable t left outer join
     (select key1,
             (case when key1 < min(key2) over (partition by key1) then key1
                   else min(key2) over (partition by key1) 
              end) as newkey
      from keypairs kp
      group by key1
     ) keymap
     on t.key = keymap.key1;
```

An update query would be similar.